# Highcharts shared tooltip making a percentage difference between series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm new using Highcharts and I have a chart with 7 series. Those series shows prices and now I need to show in the main chart tooltip the percentage difference between the prices of the main chart and just another one.
I was watching how to format the tooltip but I can't find how to solve this, maybe is easy or maybe not, so your help will be so appreciated.

Here you can see an example of my code:

```
series: [{
                name: "User Price",
                type:'line',
                data: JSON.parse(data)
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Average Price',
                color: "#E82315",
                dataLabels: false,
                visible: true,
                data: JSON.parse(precio_medio)
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Other Price',
                color: "#CC8604",
                visible: false,
                dataLabels: false,
                data: [0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,
                       0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884,0.126884]
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Other Price 2',
                color: "#F29D00",
                visible: false,
                dataLabels: false,
                data: [0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368
                       ,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368,0.124368]
            }]
```

And I want to show in the tooltip the percentage difference between the User Price and the Average price.

Thanks you all in advance.

Comment: I'm going to try this and told you the result ;)

Comment: See my latest answer, I feel you want to show what percent of your first series...See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
  formatter:function() {                  

       var pointPct='';
                var baseValue= this.points[0].point.y;
                 var tooTipTxt='';
                 console.log(baseValue);
    $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {            
        pointPct = (point.y)*100/baseValue;
        tooTipTxt   +=   "<span>"+pointPct+"</span> "

    });

     return tooTipTxt;
            }
```

Comment: you need to add line break to differentiate among various percentiles , if can put your code in fiddle it would be helpful.

Comment: One more thing, Dont forget to add useHTML:true in tooltip

Comment: Thanks you so much, it worked for me, I just had to modify one thing. Since I just want to make the percentage between some of those series, not all, I had to difference among them using "if" sentence.